# AWS CodePipeLine :Execute deploy action in diffent region than the one codepipeline is triggered in

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm setting up a pipeline to automate cloudformation stack templates deployment.

The pipeline itself is created in the aws **eu-west-1** region, but cloudformation stacks templates would be deployed in any other region.

Actually I know and can execute pipeline action in a different account, but I don't see where to specify the region I would like my template to be deployed in, like we do with aws cli : `aws --region cloudformation deploy....`.

Is there anyway to trigger a pipeline in one region and execute a `deploy action` in another region please?

The action configuration properties don't offer such possibility...

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to run aws cli deploy command from cli in the **codebuild** container and speficy the good region, But I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to deploy to multiple regions, one after the other, you could create a Code Pipeline pipeline in every region you want to deploy to, and set up S3 cross-region replication so that the output of the first pipeline becomes the input to a pipeline in the next region.

Here's a blog post explaining this further: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-a-cross-regioncross-account-code-deployment-solution-on-aws/

Comment: By the way, not supporting cross-region deployments is a conspicuous gap in Code Pipeline's feature set, it's kind of an obvious thing to have.

Answer (score 0):

Since late Nov 2018, CodePipeline supports [cross regional deploys](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-aws-codepipeline-to-perform-multi-region-deployments/). However it still leaves a lot to be desired as you need to create artifact buckets in each region and copy over the deployment artifacts (e.g. in the codebuild container as you mentioned) to them before the Deploy action is triggered. So it's not as automated as it could be, but if you go through the process of setting it up, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

CodePipeline now supports cross region deployment and for to trigger the pipeline in different region we can specify the "Region": "us-west-2" property in the action stage for CloudFormation which will trigger the deployment in that specific region.

Steps to follow for this setup:

1. Create two bucket in two different region which for example bucket in "us-east-1" and bucket in "us-west-2" (We can also use bucket already created by CodePipeline when you will setup pipeline first time in any region)
2. Configure the pipeline in such a way that is can use respective bucket while taking action in respective account.
3. specify the region in the action for CodePipeline.

Note: I have attached the sample CloudFormation template which will help you to do the cross region CloudFormation deployment.

```html
{
    "Parameters": {
        "BranchName": {
            "Description": "CodeCommit branch name for all the resources",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "master"
        },
        "RepositoryName": {
            "Description": "CodeComit repository name",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "aws-account-resources"
        },
        "CFNServiceRoleDeployA": {
            "Description": "CFN service role for create resourcecs for account-A",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/CloudFormation-service-role-cp"
        },
        "CodePipelineServiceRole": {
            "Description": "Service role for codepipeline",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/AWS-CodePipeline-Service"
        },
        "CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket1": {
            "Description": "S3 bucket to store the artifacts",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "bucket-us-east-1"
        },
        "CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket2": {
            "Description": "S3 bucket to store the artifacts",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "bucket-us-west-2"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "AppPipeline": {
            "Type": "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-cross-account-pipeline" },
                "ArtifactStores": [
                    {
                        "ArtifactStore": {
                            "Type": "S3",
                            "Location": {
                                "Ref": "CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket1"
                            }
                        },
                        "Region": "us-east-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "ArtifactStore": {
                            "Type": "S3",
                            "Location": {
                                "Ref": "CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket2"
                            }
                        },
                        "Region": "us-west-2"
                    }
                ],
                "RoleArn": {
                    "Ref": "CodePipelineServiceRole"
                },
                "Stages": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Source",
                        "Actions": [
                            {
                                "Name": "SourceAction",
                                "ActionTypeId": {
                                    "Category": "Source",
                                    "Owner": "AWS",
                                    "Version": 1,
                                    "Provider": "CodeCommit"
                                },
                                "OutputArtifacts": [
                                    {
                                        "Name": "SourceOutput"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Configuration": {
                                    "BranchName": {
                                        "Ref": "BranchName"
                                    },
                                    "RepositoryName": {
                                        "Ref": "RepositoryName"
                                    },
                                    "PollForSourceChanges": true
                                },
                                "RunOrder": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Deploy-to-account-A",
                        "Actions": [
                            {
                                "Name": "stage-1",
                                "InputArtifacts": [
                                    {
                                        "Name": "SourceOutput"
                                    }
                                ],
                              
                                
                                "ActionTypeId": {
                                    "Category": "Deploy",
                                    "Owner": "AWS",
                                    "Version": 1,
                                    "Provider": "CloudFormation"
                                },
                                "Configuration": {
                                    "ActionMode": "CREATE_UPDATE",
                                    "StackName": "cloudformation-stack-name-account-A",
                                    "TemplatePath":"SourceOutput::accountA.json",
                                    "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM",
                                    "RoleArn": {
                                        "Ref": "CFNServiceRoleDeployA"
                                    }
                                },
                                "RunOrder": 2,
                                "Region": "us-west-2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }

                    
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```